# JQuery animating 2 divs - width and left attributes

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a layout with two divs inside a container, [here's a JSFiddle of the layout](http://jsfiddle.net/YNAJZ/29/). I want to animate the right column off the display, and have the left column adjust to 100% width to fill the newly created space. This is the jQuery code I have:

```
if ($('div#right').offset().left > $('#container').width()) {
         // Bring right-column back onto display

          $('div#right').animate({
            left:'0'
          }, 600);

          $('div#left').animate({
            width:'50%'
          }, 200);
        } else {

// Animate column off display.
          $('div#right').animate({
            left:'+50%'
          }, 600);

          $('div#left').animate({
            width:'100%'
          }, 1000);
        }
```

container overflow-x is set to hidden. The problem I'm having is that expanding the left column to 100% causes the right column to appear beneath the left column, since it still takes up space within the container, and the left column is gradually moving toward taking up 100% of the container's width.

Any suggestions about how to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to animate the right column off the display?"

Comment: Please see this:  http://sscce.org

Comment: You can't animate the elements position, because you have not positioned them. Add a position, like absolute or relative, and add values to left/right properties in your css before you try to animate. When the elements are just floated jQuery has no idea where to start the animation.

Comment: I was being lazy. They are positioned in my code, but the JSFiddle was just to show layout. As you point out, jQuery won't animate a position unless a position has been set, so I thought it was obvious I had some positioning. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $('#container').click(function(){
    if (parseInt($('div#right').css('right'),10) < 0) {
             // Bring right-column back onto display
              $('div#right').animate({
                  right:'0%'
              }, 1000);

              $('div#left').animate({
                width:'45%'
              }, 600);
            } else {

    // Animate column off display.
              $('div#right').animate({
                  right:'-45%'
              }, 600);

              $('div#left').animate({
                width:'100%'
              }, 1000);
    }
```

});

This is a better solution.  Use absolute positioning instead of floats:  jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/YNAJZ/38/

Comment: This is what I had, but the contents of the `right` div look ugly as the width approaches 0%. I need the width to be kept the same. Your example looks fine as long as `right` is just a background-color.

Comment: This should be what you're looking for.  It requires using absolute positioning so it animates the location of the div, rather than the width.  Try it out and let me know if it works for you.  http://jsfiddle.net/YNAJZ/38/

Comment: I can't position the elements absolutely. This was the reason I had to post on Stackoverflow ;)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of any way to "slide" an element without absolute positions.